# Clojure: accessing protected methods through proxy or other means?

Tags: java, clojure

I'm using the SnakeYAML Java library in my Clojure project. I would like to to the equivalent of the following in Clojure:

```
class DiceConstructor extends SafeConstructor {
    public DiceConstructor() {
        this.yamlConstructors.put(new Tag("!dice"), new ConstructDice());
    }

    private class ConstructDice extends AbstractConstruct {
        public Object construct(Node node) {
            String val = (String) constructScalar((ScalarNode) node);
            int position = val.indexOf('d');
            Integer a = new Integer(val.substring(0, position));
            Integer b = new Integer(val.substring(position + 1));
            return new Dice(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

To explain: I would like to create a subclass of `SafeConstructor` that accesses the protected field `yamlConstructors` of its superclass, and adds some custom subclass of `AbstractConstruct` to `yamlConstructors`.

I was thinking to use a `proxy` for this, but it seems proxies cannot access protected fields. Are there other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using methods from [clojure.contrib.reflect](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/reflect.clj), like this:

```lisp
(require '[clojure.contrib.reflect :as reflect])

(defn dice-constructor 
  "Creates a custom SafeConstructor that understands the !dice tag"
  []
  (let [result (SafeConstructor.)
        constructor (proxy [AbstractConstruct] []
                      (construct [node]
                        (let [scalar-node (cast ScalarNode node)
                              scalar (reflect/call-method BaseConstructor 'constructScalar [ScalarNode] result scalar-node)
                              string-val (cast String scalar)]
                          (println (str "Loading: " string-val)))))]
    (.put (reflect/get-field BaseConstructor 'yamlConstructors result)
          (Tag. "!dice")
          constructor)
    result))
```

Comment: If you want to use gen-class take a look at my attempt: https://gist.github.com/edbond/7889075 Run it with `lein run`, it didn't finished I stuck at "No matching field found: yamlConstructors" and think reflect is needed.

Comment: Also read https://kotka.de/blog/2010/02/gen-class_how_it_works_and_how_to_use_it.html Nice writeup about gen-class

Comment: I came to this from Google looking for a reflection helper to access a protected field from a Java object. [This little helper fn `get-field`](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/reflect.clj#L27") does the trick. I was able to do `(get-field AmazonWebServiceClient :endpoint c)` to access the protected field `endpoint` of [class `AmazonWebServiceClient`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient.java#L106). Noting it here to save whoever is facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you can't use `proxy` because you need to for instance produce a named class, then gen-class is the next option. It is more work to use, and more flexible in it's results.

Comment: Thanks! I feel as if I don't really need a named class here (see my answer above). But I might go for gen-class if it allows me to access protected fields more easily. Does it?

Comment: Yes. I recommend the chapter on this in Clojure Programming: http://www.clojurebook.com/